# How to toggle nested ul li using jquery/javascript?

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I want to keep give toggle function for a nested ul li. In Magento I displayed the categories and its subcategories programatically in phtml like below:

```
<div class="sidebar-block">
  <ul class="cat-list">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
          <li class="category-li">
             <div class="main-cat" style="font-weight:bold;"> 
                 <?php echo $category->getName()?> </div>
                   <div class="sub-cat" style="display:none;">
                     <ul class="subcat-list">
                       <?php foreach ($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                 <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                       <?php endforeach; ?>
                      </ul>
                </div>
          </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
```

I wish to show the inner `ul` when the outer `li` is clicked. So I enabled the toggle function using jquery below:

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
    $j('li.category-li').click(function(){
        $j(this).children('ul.subcat-list').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

But it is not working. Please help me to toggle the inner ul.

Comment: Use `find()` instead of `children()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/)**

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that `.children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree`, *while .find() can traverse down multiple levels* to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

1. So this won't work as your *`ul` is not a direct a child of `li`*.
2. Also, your `ul` is always displayed, but the parent `div` is hidden. So add `.active` class to the `<div class="sub-cat">`

   ```
   .active{
       display : block;
   }
   ```

---

**Use jQuery [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)**,

```
$j(this).find('div.sub-cat').toggleClass('active');
```

or

```
$j('div.sub-cat',this).toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: Is the script which I have given correct? Because there is not even a symptom of toggle function working. And should I give any css for `.active` class. Please help me am a newbie to jquery/javascript. Kindly help me.

Comment: sorry js not working. :( should i remove `display:none` from `sub-cat` ?

Comment: It should work. Did you add the css? Just use `.toggle()` instead of `.toggleClass('active')`

Comment: Hey Its working when I used `.toggle()` instead of `.toggleClass(active)`. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is is possible to show only one ul at a time. Now when I click the first `li` its `ul` is displayed. When I click the second `li` the second `ul` is opened with the first `li` 's `ul` already opened. I want to hide the first `ul` automatically when the second `li` is clicked. Is it possible?

Comment: But here only when I click the second `li` the already opened `ul` is getting hidden. When I click the `li` of already opened `ul` it is not closing. Is it the way it should be or can we have these both above functionalities merged?

Comment: Yes we can - https://jsfiddle.net/upkynwjr/3/. You just need to modify the selectors.

Comment: When we click the `li` of the opened `ul` it is closing. only when we click the first `li` it should be closed. What should be done for that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115085/discussion-between-ramya-and-shaunak-d).